# How to compare strings in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

This drives me crazy, I have this script pasted in shell:

```
a=""; for f in $(ls -d -- */); do if [[ "$a" != "index/" ]]; then a="$a---$f--- "; fi done; echo "$a";
```

And what I get?

```
---index/---
```

How can be "index/" not equal to "index/"?

Slash? Syntax? Please help...

Comment: The shell script tells the truth: blank string `$a` and "index/" don't match.

Comment: Aside: You don't need the `$(ls)` bit: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 3):

`a` is *never* set to `"index/"`. `f` may be set to index and, as a result of that, `a` gets set to something with `---` in it.

It's a little hard to see what you're trying to do but you may want consider checking `f` in the `if` statement rather than `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ "$a" != "index/" ]];
```

you'll need instead:

```
if [[ "$f" != "index/" ]];
```